# Wordpress - Как отслеживать текущий URL ? / Добавление класса

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Есть ли возможность стандартными функциями Wordpress отслеживать, на какой странице находится пользователь, и в зависимости от текущего местоположения добавлять нужным элементам нужные классы. Приведу пример -

```css
.bl_groupButtons {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.bl_groupButtons__item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 17px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, .17), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .04);
  background-color: #232c35;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #272c32 0%, #363f4a 100%);
  outline-color: #ffb504
}

.bl_groupButtons__item:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000
}

.bl_groupButtons__item:focus,
.bl_groupButtons__item:hover {
  color: #ffb504;
  transition: .2s all;
  outline-color: #ffb504
}

.bl_groupButtons__item.active {
  background-color: #ffb504;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .55) 100%)
}

.bl_groupButtons__item.active:hover {
  color: #000;
  transition: .2s all
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_groupButtons">
  <a class="bl_groupButtons__item active" href="/">Игровые автоматы</a>
  <a class="bl_groupButtons__item" href="/bonuses">Бездипозитные бонусы</a>
  <a class="bl_groupButtons__item" href="/news">Новости</a>
</div>
```

Если пользователь находится на страницах бонусов (example.com/bonuses), то только второй ссылке присваивается класс active. Если на странице новостей (example.com/news), то третьей ссылке. Во всех других случаях, класс active присваивается первой ссылке. (Технически я могу это отслеживать с помощью JS на стороне клиента, но что-то мне подсказывает, что есть вариант правильнее).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WordPress есть функция `body_class()`, которая используется в заголовке всеми правильными темами. Эта функция добавляет классы к body, которые указывают на принадлежность к текущей странице (URL).

Не нужен никакой js, с помощью css вы сможете активировать нужные классы на нужных страницах.